# Convert from '\ud835' format to "" in c# [UWP]

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, surrogate-pairs

I have a string with some wonky characters (for example) `" "`. I need to check if a List contains the first item in the string. But if I index it, it always becomes  `\ud835`. After using Char.ConvertFromUtf32(`\ud835`) and some other attempts, I simply can't find out how to get the first item as a "".

Comment: I'm not following.  `'\Ud835'` is a "high surrogate" and not a valid character by itself.  Is your string "Lead Backend" and rendered in a wonky font, or is that lead character really wonky and represented by a Unicode surrogate pair?

Comment: @Flydog57 it's represented by a Unicode surrogate pair

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347799/how-do-i-create-a-string-with-a-surrogate-pair-inside-of-it.  Otherwise, search around for stuff on "surrogate pairs".  I've never had to play with them

Comment: What is the "first item from the string"? ? ?

Comment: @JacobKrall "" is the first item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is represented with a surrogate pair in UTF-16, the encoding used by .NET.

A surrogate *pair* is represented with *two* characters:

```
        var s = " ";
        Console.WriteLine(new string(new[] { s[0], s[1] }) == "");
```

There are built-in helper methods like [`Char.ConvertToUtf32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdh8k14a(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Char.IsSurrogate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xe6etk(v=vs.110).aspx) which you can use to figure out if you are in this situation.

Comment: Upon further examination it's in UTF16, I think

Comment: Yes, like I said, .NET uses the UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: sorry I'd missed that, but how do I get a "" back after indexing for the first value. "\ud835" != "" so that doesn't work

Comment: Please read my answer. ***Two*** indexes are required to get "" back.

Comment: Yep, thank you. I just looked at .Count() of the string " " and understand now. thanks again

Comment: @AvishaiDernis You can use things like `var first = StringInfo.GetNextTextElement(" ");` or do `var info = new StringInfo(" "); var first = info.SubstringByTextElements(0, 1);` to get out the entire first Unicode character `""` and not just half of the surrogate pair.